# Plugins ignored by Vue webpack template

Tags: webpack, vue.js

Here's my webpack config, in which I'm trying add the IgnorePlugin plugin in order to remove the locales from moment when building my app. However when executing the "npm run build" to compile the production build, I'm not being able to remove the locales from moment. Any idea on what might be wrong?

index.js file

```
'use strict'
// Template version: 1.3.1
// see http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack for documentation.

const path = require('path')
var webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = {
    dev: {

        // Paths
        assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
        assetsPublicPath: '/',
        proxyTable: {},

        // Various Dev Server settings
        host: 'localhost', // can be overwritten by process.env.HOST
        port: 8080, // can be overwritten by process.env.PORT, if port is in use, a free one will be determined
        autoOpenBrowser: false,
        errorOverlay: true,
        notifyOnErrors: true,
        poll: false, // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-watchoptions-


        /**
         * Source Maps
         */

        // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#development
        devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

        // If you have problems debugging vue-files in devtools,
        // set this to false - it *may* help
        // https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/options.html#cachebusting
        cacheBusting: true,

        cssSourceMap: true
    },

    build: {
        // Template for index.html
        index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),

        // Paths
        assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
        assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
        assetsPublicPath: '/',

        plugins: [
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/)
        ],

        /**
         * Source Maps
         */

        productionSourceMap: true,
        // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#production
        devtool: '#source-map',

        // Gzip off by default as many popular static hosts such as
        // Surge or Netlify already gzip all static assets for you.
        // Before setting to `true`, make sure to:
        // npm install --save-dev compression-webpack-plugin
        productionGzip: false,
        productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],

        // Run the build command with an extra argument to
        // View the bundle analyzer report after build finishes:
        // `npm run build --report`
        // Set to `true` or `false` to always turn it on or off
        bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
    }
}
```

prod.env.js file

```
'use strict'
module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: '"production"'
}
```

dev.env.js

```
'use strict'
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const prodEnv = require('./prod.env')

module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"'
})
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem? It works? If yes, mark an answer as valid in order to mark as resolved and keep S.O clean. If no, try updating the question and we will try to help you! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to this thread on Github pointed by the official documentation: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2373

You could try like `ldrick` answer:

These are the relevant parts in my webpack.config.js.

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = () => {
    return {
        // ...
        resolve: {
            // Use src Moment.js to be optimized and packed.
            alias: {
                moment$: "moment/src/moment",
            },
        },
        // ...
        plugins: [
            // Switch context for Moment.js locales.
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, context => {
                // Don't touch anything else then "moment".
                if (!/\/moment\//.test(context.context)) {
                    return;
                }
                // Working with "moment/src/moment" instead of "moment" requires
                // redirecting "./locale" back to "../../locale".
                Object.assign(context, {
                    // Want all locales, enable this line.
                    // regExp: /^\.\/\w+/,
                    // Just use some locales, enable this line.
                    // regExp: /de|fr|hu/,
                    // Don't use any locales except default "en".
                    regExp: undefined,
                    request: "../../locale",
                });
            }),
            // ...
        ],
        // ...
    };
};
```

Or try instead of `new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/)` this expression (it seems to be the work to not importing the locates files on building):

```
new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /moment[\/\\]locale$/,
      /en|de|fr|es|pl|ua|ru/
    ),
```

*(change the langs according what you are using).*

Hope it helps or at least give you some light!